# Source Code shows as rectangles instead of characters

Tags: eclipse

I've a very weird problem:

after upgrading from Ubuntu 10.10. to 11.04 (new installation), I have weird problems with the Eclipse editor.

When writing Java code (new Project was created) I type

```
System.out.println("bla")
```

and then "out" is shown as rectangles only. Weird is that for about half a second I see "System.out.println" and then the editor changes it to System.[][][].println (not really [] (here I used two brackets), it is shown as rectangles).
See the attached file for an example.

This is very weird. I've never had this before with any Ubuntu, Java or Eclipse version.

Currently, I use: Ubuntu 11.04. Eclipse 3.6 (latest download from June 7th) and Java 1.6.0_25.

Eclipse and Ubuntu Terminal is set to UTF-8.

The problem also happens when using KDE instead of Gnome.

Any ideas what could be wrong here and how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you install it from the repo or did you install it manually? I normally install eclipse manually (put the code in `~/runtime/eclipse`) and it never broke when upgrading [I'm also running ubuntu 11.04 (64bit)]

Comment: I've installed manually... my eclipse is located in ~/Development/eclipse and i'm using ubuntu 11.04 32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem :)
We should install those packages and restart computer...

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer mplayer-fonts ttf-xfree86-nonfree xfs cabextract ttf-liberation ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt-get install ttf-larabie-straight ttf-larabie-deco xfonts-terminus-dos xfonts-terminus xfonts-terminus-oblique xfonts-mona tv-fonts ttf-tuffy ttf-sjfonts ttf-georgewilliams ttf-fifthhorseman-dkg-handwriting ttf-essays1743 ttf-opensymbol ttf-mgopen ttf-freefont ttf-dustin ttf-dejavu-extra ttf-dejavu-core ttf-dejavu ttf-bpg-georgian-fonts equivs ttf-sil-gentium gnome-specimen bsd-mailx dctrl-tools devscripts diffstat dput libapt-pkg-perl libauthen-sasl-perl libdevel-symdump-perl libio-pty-perl libio-stringy-perl libipc-run-perl libparse-debcontrol-perl libpod-coverage-perl libterm-size-perl libtest-pod-perl lintian patchutils postfix wdiff
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax highlighting set, and the font or font style for whatever type "out" is classified as in your syntax highlighting (class variable?) cannot be found.

Comment: i know that is classified, but before upgrading my os it worked normally... and what about static fields?